# How to open the folder location on click of a button using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click of a button, it should open the popup which will show the folder location. The screenshot posted indicates exactly what is needed.
[image]

I should be able to select any folder from the tab.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m8x2fobw/) web page.

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to have the file picker opened at a specific location which is not possible from what I know.

Comment: Hi @The KNVB, Thank you for your reply. This approach is for file selection. How can I do the same for folder selection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.